# Do we have to consider the cryptographic properties of the decryption, if we're only using the encryption?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher

[Treyfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treyfer) for example has slower diffusion in decryption. It has full diffusion between words in 2 rounds for encryption and 7 rounds for decryption.

Do we have to consider the (bad) cryptographic properties of the decryption algorithm, if we're only using the encryption algorithm? (For example we are using Treyfer in CTR mode.)

Differently worded: Do we have to consider the bad cryptographic properties of the decryption algorithm if the encryption algorithm can be considered strong as we're usually only using the encryption algorithm?

Comment: Sounds like a very weird cipher. Most ciphers I know differ by only one round or so. I'd guess it has been designed with some unusual goals in mind, like very high parallelism in one direction and not as a general purpose block-cipher.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I just gave Treyfer as an example.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Does decryption matter for what? Can we ignore decryption for what?

Comment: @Gilles For security of encryption.

Comment: I think the question could be rephrased as: "Do we have to consider the bad cryptographic properties of the decryption algorithm if the encryption algorithm can be considered strong as we're usually only using the encryption algorithm?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diffusion is a requirement for a secure cipher, but it is not by itself sufficient. So even if a certain number of rounds has "full diffusion", it does not mean that the number of rounds is enough. In the case of Treyfer, the decryption direction requires five more rounds for full diffusion, but the suggested number of rounds is much higher at 32. (Even that is not really secure, because the key schedule is broken.)

However, if considering block ciphers more generally the question is whether a block cipher can be secure in the encryption direction without being secure in the decryption direction. The answer is probably yes. For example, [Luby and Rackoff showed](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0217022) that a three round Feistel network with a secure PRF is secure against adversaries without access to a decryption oracle, but needed four rounds to prove security against adversaries with such access (which they called strong PRP).

So there seems to be a security difference between a block cipher used only in the forward direction and a block cipher used in both directions.

Comment: Were bad cryptographic properties in decryption algorithm ever used in known/chosen-plaintext or ciphertext-only attack?

Comment: @LightBit, I don't know of a case where the weakness of decryption specifically, without encryption being similarly weak, would have been used. When talking about the cipher that is: attacks such as padding oracle attack do target weaknesses in decryption more generally.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't constrain what an attacker can do. If a chosen ciphertext attack or a meet in the middle attack is mounted bad properties of the decryption become relevant.

Comment: But, you can constrain what an attacker can do with your key.